# Why would RowFilter not be working properly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the two type of code below to filter the record from the data table. But only one is working and other is not.

```
var filter = "FLD_PARENT_ID = " + Pack["FLD_ID"] + " AND FLD_TYPE=1";

DataView dv = ds_pack.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = filter ; //This is filtering a row 

DataRow[] SRows = ds_pack.Tables[0].Select(filter); //But this type not return a row
```

I need DataRow array only.

I user the same filter value to the two methods.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: do u get any error ??

Comment: What is the ds_pack.Tables[0].Select(filter) return type??

Comment: Really difficult to understand, Both properties requires a string that is compatible with the same rules of Expression property. Do you have changed some values in the DataTable?

Comment: By the way, what is Pack["FLD_ID"]? And do you have null values in the column FLD_PARENT_ID?

Answer (score 0):

Not about filter, but Linq alternative

```
var SRows = ds_pack.Tables[0].Select()
                 .Where(dr => dr["FLD_PARENT_ID"].ToString()== Pack["FLD_ID"] 
                              && dr["FLD_TYPE"].ToString()=="1")
```

Comment: No. He said to return a datarow array.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany "But this type not return a row" - I suppose it means a single row

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var filter = "[FLD_PARENT_ID] = " + Pack["FLD_ID"] + " AND [FLD_TYPE]=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
 DataRow[] drs = ds_pack.Tables[0].Select("FLD_PARENT_ID = " + Pack["FLD_ID"].ToString() + " AND FLD_TYPE=1");
```

OR

```
 DataTable dtpacks = ds_pack.Tables[0];
 var filter = "FLD_PARENT_ID = " + Pack["FLD_ID"].ToString() + " AND FLD_TYPE=1";

 DataRow[] drs = dtpacks.Select(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're applying filter to DataView's RowFilter property, you'll get filtered result and it will be reflected to Original Datatable as well. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As you need DataRow Array, you should use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method.